# Join de una tabla en otra dos veces, regresa dos veces la misma row

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Tengo este query en querybuilder, lo voy a escribir en sql para leerse mas facil.
el problema es que me regresa las rows repetidas por cada join que hago, la tabla contiene 3 ids,  categoria_id, subcategoria_id y familia_id y los tres hacen referencia a la misma tabla. como puedo hacer join a dicha tabla pero recibir el join en los tres diferentes ids?

mi propuesta, la cual regresa los registros repetidos pero con los datos que busco.

```
 SELECT rssp.sucursa_serviciol_id, rssp.servicio_id, rssp.sucursal_id, s.clave_interna, s.nombre, cscs.nombre as nombre_categoria, cscs2.nombre as nombre_subcategoria, cscs3.nombre as nombre_familia
FROM rel_sucursales_servicios_paquetes AS rssp

JOIN servicios AS s ON rssp.servicio_id = s.servicio_id
JOIN cat_servicios_categorias_subcategorias_familias cscs ON cscs.categoria_familia_id = s.categoria_id 
JOIN cat_servicios_categorias_subcategorias_familias cscs2 ON cscs2.categoria_familia_id = s.subcategoria_id 
JOIN cat_servicios_categorias_subcategorias_familias cscs3 ON cscs3.categoria_familia_id = s.familia_id
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes agregar datos de ejemplo? de paso, tambien decirnos como se unen las tablas? si podes hacer un fiddle donde podamos probar, mucho mejor!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.